# The requested URL /phpmyadmin/import.php was not found on this server

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Whenever i try to execute any sql command.I am sgetting this message in my mysql browser window.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin/import.php was not found on this server.
```

Like

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `employee`
```

but strange fact is that if a click on browse tab of any table it executing default selection command any my data is showing. Additionally my application(PHP) is getting data without any error.

Comment: What is the operating system? Maybe file permissions prevent import.php from being accessed?

Comment: windows xp but all things were working properly

Comment: Does the file really exist? If not, maybe you can get it from a phpmyadmin download, and put it there so the error goes away.

Comment: where to check that file

Comment: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ is where you can get the file, and on your computer you need to find the phpmyadmin directory, and look right inside it, you should see an import.php file. If not, go get the file and put it there.

Comment: yes in wamp/apps/phpmyadmin import file were missing